# Unexpected behaviour of require() in electron when using relative paths

Tags: node.js, electron, require

I would appreciate some clarification on the following matter:

I am starting to learn electron and wanted to setup a small example to test requiring-mechanism.

Folder structure as follows:

```
main.js
node_modules
html
 |-index.html
[...]
js
 |-test.js
 |-test2.js
```

*test2.js* contains just one function that I export.

Now from what I read online, *require(...)* should resolve relative paths, but if in *test.js* (which is used in *index.html*) I use:

```
const aTest = require('./test2.js');
```

produces a *module not found*, while:

```
const aTest = require('../js/test2.js');
```

works just fine, which I find quite counterintuitive and from reading on SO and other sites, I thought first version should work as well. Further testing (with nested folders) indicated that the path is relative to *node_modules*.

--|EDIT(add): Further testing made me assume that the path is rather set relative to the html directory. For example:

```
console.log(__dirname)
```

in *test.js* prints the path to the html directory.|--

Why does it behave that way? Did I make a setup mistake?

(PS: I found several posts providing information about avoiding ../../../someModule, but as far as I understood all were assuming "pathing" relative to the requiring file, so that didn't help me resolve my problem.)

Comment: Is electron installed only within `package.json` or globally ?

Comment: I did a "npm list -g electron" which didn't find it and electron is listed as devDepenency in my package.json.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, `require(...)` can resolve relative paths, but from a file which has itself been *required*.

You're indicating that `test.js` is *used* in `index.html`, and the *module not found* error message you get suggests that it is included using the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="../js/test.js"></script>
```

Try using a `require()` statement instead:

```
<script>require('../js/test.js');</script>
```

then the code inside `test.js` should work properly:

```
const aTest = require('./test2.js');
// aTest();
```

Comment: Interesting! And that worked :) Thank you for clearing that up for me and my apologies for the late response to your answer!